# When using scp command, it fails as 'bash: bash command not found' . How to resolve it?

Tags: bash, centos, scp

When i am trying to copy a file using scp, it says bash: bash:: command not found. I am able to execute help command for scp but unable to use it.

```
[root@centosgui ansibleplay]# scp --help
unknown option -- -
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
[root@centosgui ansibleplay]# scp CentOs-DockerManagedPluginconfiguration.yml root@othermachine-cv:/root/managed-plugin
root@othermachine-cv's password:
bash: bash:: command not found
```

I am using CentOS 7.5. other commands like vim, ls ,cat and etc are working fine in that machine. How to solve this?

When i run the below command, it shows bash command not found then display the help of scp command.

```
[root@centosgui ansibleplay]# ssh root@othermachine-cv scp --help
root@othermachine-cv's password:
bash: bash:: command not found
bash: bash:: command not found
unknown option -- -
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

When i run the below command as OP instructs

```
[root@centosgui ~]# ssh root@othermachine-cv grep -n "bash:" .bash{rc,_profile}
root@othermachine-cv's password:
bash: bash:: command not found
bash: bash:: command not found
```

From centosgui ,i am able to copy file to other centos machines.
Also from othermachine-cv i am able copy the file from centosgui using scp.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It shown the help documentation of scp correctly in that machine. But i notice that i am able to copy file to some other machines. May be the problem will be with the othermachine-cv ..

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have updated the command result in my question (for cleaner view)

Comment: OK, so it looks like some profile script on the server is broken.

Comment: Did you check if the file was uploaded or not? It might have, despite the error.

Comment: You might also have more luck with `sftp`

Comment: `scp` shows the usage output if no other options are provided, and in this case both `-h` and `--help` are not valid options for `scp`. You get the same output (without the error message) if you simply run `ssh root@othermachine-cv scp`.

Comment: @eblock Sure, but that's actually not really the problem. The problem is the `bash:: command not found`, not the `unknown option -- -`.

Comment: Please run `ssh root@othermachine-cv grep -n "bash:" .bash{rc,_profile}` and tell us the output.

Comment: Do you get the problem when you `ssh root@othermachine-cv` ?

Comment: @RoVo I have updated the output

Comment: Are you able to log into the remote system at all and have a look at what the root user's shell is (probably `bash`) and whether `bash` is actually installed at all on the system?

Comment: @Kusalananda from that machine othermachine-cv ,we did scp and copy the files from centosgui . So bash is working on that machine

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Ok, so `scp` in _the other direction_ works. Then there can be any number of other causes for the error, ranging from a faulty shell startup script to setting the SSH `RemoteCommand` to something invalid, or anything in-between.

Comment: It seems that some initialization script or something else is interpreting the `bash: cmd: error` message as a command as in `bash -c "$(bash -c foo 2>&1)"` => `bash: bash:: command not found`.

Comment: Searching for the `bash:` string in your scripts is a pointless exercise ;-)